# Creating a "pen drive program" with Python

Tags: python, windows

I'm bringing you this issue: I'm trying to create a program to run in Windows using PyQT, to work on a pen drive. My idea is: I plug my pen drive, and everything that I need to run the program is there, including Python 3, PyQT, etc.. I don't want the user to install all the requirements, I just want one executable that install all the programs necessary and then, there will be the executable to open the program. Considering, of course, that Python 3 is not installed in this Windows Machine

Just wondering how can I do it? Do you guys have any idea?

Thanks,

Gus.

Comment: I imagine you'll need your user to install Python 3. It makes no difference if Python 3 is "installed" on the USB drive - it'll run on their computer, not as if the drive was a computer.

Comment: Yes, the user must install Python 3 to run it, but there will be more applications, so I don't want the user to install more then one thing. I want them to install one executable that will install Python 3, PyQT, etc..

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea - not sure if that would work under your specific conditions (PyQT etc), but couldn't you run it from the pen drive directly? As in create a Python virtual environment (for example using venv, with all the dependencies) on the pendrive and then call your program using the python interpreter in the installed virtual environment.

Or use the virtual environment and it's interpreter to install the dependencies?

Comment: Is is possible to install Python + PythonQT + codes using the virtual environment?

Comment: That's why I said it was an idea - I'm not sure, especially about the PyQT (and dependencies) :( But, considering the fact that virtual environment is basically just a bunch of directories in specific format and you can start a Python program with specific interpreter coming from the virtual environment without actually "activating" that virtual environment (and have access to the packages installed for that virtual environment), I don't see a reason why it shouldn't be possible. Of course, the links would have to be relative... In the end, you'll have to try.

Comment: Jeez, I'm such a fool... Totally forgot that you'll need different python interpreter for Linux and Windows... Sorry:( But if it's just one platform, it still might work.